# Linux zip command - adding date elements to file name

Tags: date, zip

occasionally I run a backup of my phpbb forum files from the Shell command line:

zip -r forum_backup ~/public_html/forum/*

I'd like to add date elements to the file name, so that the zip file created is automatically formed as

```
forum_backup_05182013.zip
```

any other similar current date format would also be acceptable

Answer (score 4):

```
now=$(date +"%m%d%Y")
zip -r forum_backup_$now ~/public_html/forum/
```

Comment: Very helpful (Frosty and Yiz). Please show how to add time also - just hour(24 military hour) and minute.

Answer (score 1):

Without defining a variable first you can do it in one line with

```
zip -r "forum_backup_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" filelist
```

As taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261079/how-can-i-create-zip-file-with-the-date-in-its-name)

Answer (score 0):

the following shell command, change the format as you want

```
FORMAT="%Y%m%d"
_DATE=$(date +"$FORMAT" )
zip -r "forum_bakcup_${_DATE}" ~/public_html/forum/*
```